# Подскажите по синтаксису Python: как вставить целые числа в строку

Tags: python, файлы, синтаксис

Задача обработать несколько файлов, имена которых формируются автоматически в виде `file+i+j`, где `i` и `j` - целые числа (т.е. имена вида `file11`, `file12`...). Как грамотно обратиться к нужному файлу, например, в такой строке:

```
f = open("file+i+j.txt", "wb")
```

И второй аналогичный вопрос, как обратиться к переменному `url` (в который тоже входят `i` и `j`)

```
url ='http://api.wikimapia.org/function=box&bbox["i","j"]&count=50000&format=kml&pack=gzip'
```

Как грамотно вписать эти `["i","j"]`?

Answer (score 5):

```
f = open("file{0}{1}.txt".format(i,j), "wb")
```

Comment: Добавлю: для питона3 рекомендуется использовать format, а не операнд %

Answer (score 4):

Форматирование строк, операция %.

```
f = open("file%d%d.txt" % (i,j), "wb")
url ='http://api.wikimapia.org/function=box&bbox["%d","%d"]&count=50000&format=kml&pack=gzip' % (i, j)
```

Comment: Спасибо!
А как быть с url?

Comment: точно также

Comment: добавлено в ответ

Answer (score 0):

Альтернативная опция - f-string

```
f = open(f"file{i}{j}.txt", "wb")
url =f'http://api.wikimapia.org/function=box&bbox["{i}","{j}"]&count=50000&format=kml&pack=gzip'
```